# Content is not adjusting with window size (width) css

Tags: css, window, resize, responsive

[image]

I want to create a Dashboard where I see the sidebar on the left (green) and the content on the right (blue). I was able to split the content (right side) into classs **.split-top**, **.split-bottom-left** amd **.split-bottom-right** (yellow). All the classes are sourounded by the class **"member-content"** (blue) which has unfortunately an **overflow** (check Firefox Inspektor). I tried to get rid of this by declaring **max-width: calc(100% - 40px - 250px)** for member-content but it is not changing anything. 250px is my sidebar widh and 40px is equal to 2 times of margin.
My goal is that the content for split-bottom-right and split-top adjusting by resizing the width of the browser. In addition the scrollbar is then not visible on the bottom.

In other words: I want to see the full content with the borders for the top box and the right box each time I open the browser and resize the browser. All yellow boxes should resize themself automatically.

Is it possible to create it without flex-box, css grid and JS or JQuery? I would like to avoid using all 4. If not I would prefer using flex-box, CSS Gris and JQuery.

```css
/* Split the screen in half */
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Work+Sans:wght@500&display=swap');


* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: Work Sans, sans-serif;
  
}



.member-content{
  background-color: #f1f3f7;
  position: absolute;
  width: calc(40px + 250px + 100%);
  height: 100%;
  overflow-x: hidden;  
  scrollbar-width: none;


}

.member-content .split-top {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 250px;
  height: calc(20% - 40px);
  max-width: calc(100% - 40px - 250px);
  scrollbar-width: none;
  overflow-x: hidden;

  padding: 20px 20px 20px 20px;
  margin: 20px 20px 20px 20px;
  background-color: #fff;
  box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15) 2.4px 2.4px 3.2px;
  border-radius: 25px;


}
.split-left {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 250px;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  background-color: #2b479a;
  color: white;
  scrollbar-width: none;
  padding: 20px 0px 20px 20px;
z-index: 9;
}

.member-content .split-bottom-left {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20%;
  left: 250px;
  height: calc(80% - 40px);
  width: calc(30% - 40px);
  overflow-x: hidden;
  scrollbar-width: none;
  padding: 20px 20px 20px 20px;
  background-color: #fff;
  box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15) 2.4px 2.4px 3.2px;
  border-radius: 25px;
  margin: 20px 20px 20px 20px;

}

.member-content .split-bottom-right {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20%;
  left: calc(30% + 250px);
  height: calc(80% - 40px);
  width: calc(70% - 40px - 250px);
  overflow-x: hidden;

  scrollbar-width: none;
  padding: 20px 20px 20px 20px;
  background-color: #fff;
  box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15) 2.4px 2.4px 3.2px;
  border-radius: 25px;
  margin: 20px 20px 20px 20px;
}

.split-top::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none;
}
.split-left::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none;
}
.split-bottom-left::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none;
}
.split-bottom-right::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none;
}






.stats-games{
          width: 20%;
          height: 50%;
          border-radius: 10px;
          background-color: white;
          display: block;
          position: absolute;
}

.logo-text{
  background-color: #2b479a;
  color: black;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  position:fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 250px;
  height: 60px;
}

.logo-image{
  display: block;
}

.logo-toggle{

  display: block;
}


.items-menu{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding: 10px 10px; 
}



.header-menu{
  color: blue;
}

.category-header-text{
  margin: 20px 0 20px 0;
  display: block;
  color: grey;
  font-size: 12px;
}

.sidear-dropdown-without-arrow{
  margin: 20px 0 0 0;
}

.subheader-text{
  margin: 20px 0 0 0;
}

li{
  list-style: none;
}

li a{
  text-decoration: none;
  color: grey;
}

li a:hover{
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
}

.navigation-bar{
  margin-top: 50px;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link href='https://unpkg.com/boxicons@2.1.4/css/boxicons.min.css' rel='stylesheet'>
</head>

<body>

    <div class="side-bar-left">
        <div class="split-left">
            <div class="centered">
                <div class="logo-text">
                    <p class="logo-image">LOGO</p>
                    <p class="logo-toggle">HAM</p>
                </div>
                <div class="navigation-bar">
                    <div class="side-bar-menu">
                        <span class="category-header-text">MENU</span>
                        <div class="menu-menu">
                            <div class="submenu-menu">
                                <div class="sidear-dropdown-without-arrow">
                                    <i class='bx bx-cheese'></i>
                                    <span class="header-text">Dashboards</span>
                                </div>
                                <div class="items-menu">
                                    <li class="subheader-text">
                                        <span>
                                            <a href="portfolio.html" target="_blank">Products</a>
                                        </span>
                                    </li>

                                    <li class="subheader-text">
                                        <span>
                                            <a href="portfolio.html" target="_blank">Product Detail</a>
                                        </span>
                                    </li>

                                    <li class="subheader-text">
                                        <span>
                                            <a href="portfolio.html" target="_blank">Orders</a>
                                        </span>
                                    </li>


                                    <li class="subheader-text">
                                        <span>
                                            <a href="portfolio.html" target="_blank">See my portfolio</a>
                                        </span>
                                    </li>


                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="side-bar-menu">
                        <span class="category-header-text">MENU</span>
                        <div class="menu-menu">
                            <div class="submenu-menu">
                                <div class="sidear-dropdown-without-arrow">
                                    <i class='bx bx-cheese'></i>
                                    <span class="header-text">Dashboards</span>
                                </div>
                                <div class="items-menu">
                                    <li class="subheader-text">
                                        <span>
                                            <a href="portfolio.html" target="_blank">Products</a>
                                        </span>
                                    </li>

                                    <li class="subheader-text">
                                        <span>
                                            <a href="portfolio.html" target="_blank">Product Detail</a>
                                        </span>
                                    </li>

                                    <li class="subheader-text">
                                        <span>
                                            <a href="portfolio.html" target="_blank">Orders</a>
                                        </span>
                                    </li>


                                    <li class="subheader-text">
                                        <span>
                                            <a href="portfolio.html" target="_blank">See my portfolio</a>
                                        </span>
                                    </li>


                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>


                    <div class="side-bar-menu">
                        <span class="category-header-text">MENU</span>
                        <div class="menu-menu">
                            <div class="submenu-menu">
                                <div class="sidear-dropdown-without-arrow">
                                    <i class='bx bx-cheese'></i>
                                    <span class="header-text">Dashboards</span>
                                </div>
                                <div class="items-menu">
                                    <li class="subheader-text">
                                        <span>
                                            <a href="portfolio.html" target="_blank">Products</a>
                                        </span>
                                    </li>

                                    <li class="subheader-text">
                                        <span>
                                            <a href="portfolio.html" target="_blank">Product Detail</a>
                                        </span>
                                    </li>

                                    <li class="subheader-text">
                                        <span>
                                            <a href="portfolio.html" target="_blank">Orders</a>
                                        </span>
                                    </li>


                                    <li class="subheader-text">
                                        <span>
                                            <a href="portfolio.html" target="_blank">See my portfolio</a>
                                        </span>
                                    </li>


                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="side-bar-menu">
                        <span class="category-header-text">MENU</span>
                        <div class="menu-menu">
                            <div class="submenu-menu">
                                <div class="sidear-dropdown-without-arrow">
                                    <i class='bx bx-cheese'></i>
                                    <span class="header-text">Dashboards</span>
                                </div>
                                <div class="items-menu">
                                    <li class="subheader-text">
                                        <span>
                                            <a href="portfolio.html" target="_blank">Products</a>
                                        </span>
                                    </li>

                                    <li class="subheader-text">
                                        <span>
                                            <a href="portfolio.html" target="_blank">Product Detail</a>
                                        </span>
                                    </li>

                                    <li class="subheader-text">
                                        <span>
                                            <a href="portfolio.html" target="_blank">Orders</a>
                                        </span>
                                    </li>


                                    <li class="subheader-text">
                                        <span>
                                            <a href="portfolio.html" target="_blank">See my portfolio</a>
                                        </span>
                                    </li>


                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="member-content">


        <div class="split-top">
            <div class="centered">
                <h2>This is the split-top</h2>
                <p>Some text.</p>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="split-bottom-left">
            <div class="centered">
                <img src="img_avatar.png" alt="Avatar man">
                <h2>This is the left split-bottom-left</h2>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Vel quibusdam quaerat suscipit consequuntur maiores commodi omnis voluptatibus fugiat repellat nemo, maxime explicabo architecto nostrum officia, quisquam dignissimos deserunt perferendis soluta!</p>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Vel quibusdam quaerat suscipit consequuntur maiores commodi omnis voluptatibus fugiat repellat nemo, maxime explicabo architecto nostrum officia, quisquam dignissimos deserunt perferendis soluta!</p>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Vel quibusdam quaerat suscipit consequuntur maiores commodi omnis voluptatibus fugiat repellat nemo, maxime explicabo architecto nostrum officia, quisquam dignissimos deserunt perferendis soluta!</p>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Vel quibusdam quaerat suscipit consequuntur maiores commodi omnis voluptatibus fugiat repellat nemo, maxime explicabo architecto nostrum officia, quisquam dignissimos deserunt perferendis soluta!</p>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Vel quibusdam quaerat suscipit consequuntur maiores commodi omnis voluptatibus fugiat repellat nemo, maxime explicabo architecto nostrum officia, quisquam dignissimos deserunt perferendis soluta!</p>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Vel quibusdam quaerat suscipit consequuntur maiores commodi omnis voluptatibus fugiat repellat nemo, maxime explicabo architecto nostrum officia, quisquam dignissimos deserunt perferendis soluta!</p>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Vel quibusdam quaerat suscipit consequuntur maiores commodi omnis voluptatibus fugiat repellat nemo, maxime explicabo architecto nostrum officia, quisquam dignissimos deserunt perferendis soluta!</p>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Vel quibusdam quaerat suscipit consequuntur maiores commodi omnis voluptatibus fugiat repellat nemo, maxime explicabo architecto nostrum officia, quisquam dignissimos deserunt perferendis soluta!</p>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Vel quibusdam quaerat suscipit consequuntur maiores commodi omnis voluptatibus fugiat repellat nemo, maxime explicabo architecto nostrum officia, quisquam dignissimos deserunt perferendis soluta!</p>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Vel quibusdam quaerat suscipit consequuntur maiores commodi omnis voluptatibus fugiat repellat nemo, maxime explicabo architecto nostrum officia, quisquam dignissimos deserunt perferendis soluta!</p>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Vel quibusdam quaerat suscipit consequuntur maiores commodi omnis voluptatibus fugiat repellat nemo, maxime explicabo architecto nostrum officia, quisquam dignissimos deserunt perferendis soluta!</p>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Vel quibusdam quaerat suscipit consequuntur maiores commodi omnis voluptatibus fugiat repellat nemo, maxime explicabo architecto nostrum officia, quisquam dignissimos deserunt perferendis soluta!</p>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Vel quibusdam quaerat suscipit consequuntur maiores commodi omnis voluptatibus fugiat repellat nemo, maxime explicabo architecto nostrum officia, quisquam dignissimos deserunt perferendis soluta!</p>

            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="split-bottom-right">
            <div class="centered">
                <img src="img_avatar.png" alt="Avatar man">
                <h2>This is the right split-bottom-right</h2>
                <p>Some text here too.</p>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Vel quibusdam quaerat suscipit consequuntur maiores commodi omnis voluptatibus fugiat repellat nemo, maxime explicabo architecto nostrum officia, quisquam dignissimos deserunt perferendis soluta!</p>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Vel quibusdam quaerat suscipit consequuntur maiores commodi omnis voluptatibus fugiat repellat nemo, maxime explicabo architecto nostrum officia, quisquam dignissimos deserunt perferendis soluta!</p>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Vel quibusdam quaerat suscipit consequuntur maiores commodi omnis voluptatibus fugiat repellat nemo, maxime explicabo architecto nostrum officia, quisquam dignissimos deserunt perferendis soluta!</p>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Vel quibusdam quaerat suscipit consequuntur maiores commodi omnis voluptatibus fugiat repellat nemo, maxime explicabo architecto nostrum officia, quisquam dignissimos deserunt perferendis soluta!</p>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Vel quibusdam quaerat suscipit consequuntur maiores commodi omnis voluptatibus fugiat repellat nemo, maxime explicabo architecto nostrum officia, quisquam dignissimos deserunt perferendis soluta!</p>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Vel quibusdam quaerat suscipit consequuntur maiores commodi omnis voluptatibus fugiat repellat nemo, maxime explicabo architecto nostrum officia, quisquam dignissimos deserunt perferendis soluta!</p>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Vel quibusdam quaerat suscipit consequuntur maiores commodi omnis voluptatibus fugiat repellat nemo, maxime explicabo architecto nostrum officia, quisquam dignissimos deserunt perferendis soluta!</p>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Vel quibusdam quaerat suscipit consequuntur maiores commodi omnis voluptatibus fugiat repellat nemo, maxime explicabo architecto nostrum officia, quisquam dignissimos deserunt perferendis soluta!</p>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Vel quibusdam quaerat suscipit consequuntur maiores commodi omnis voluptatibus fugiat repellat nemo, maxime explicabo architecto nostrum officia, quisquam dignissimos deserunt perferendis soluta!</p>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Vel quibusdam quaerat suscipit consequuntur maiores commodi omnis voluptatibus fugiat repellat nemo, maxime explicabo architecto nostrum officia, quisquam dignissimos deserunt perferendis soluta!</p>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Vel quibusdam quaerat suscipit consequuntur maiores commodi omnis voluptatibus fugiat repellat nemo, maxime explicabo architecto nostrum officia, quisquam dignissimos deserunt perferendis soluta!</p>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Vel quibusdam quaerat suscipit consequuntur maiores commodi omnis voluptatibus fugiat repellat nemo, maxime explicabo architecto nostrum officia, quisquam dignissimos deserunt perferendis soluta!</p>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Vel quibusdam quaerat suscipit consequuntur maiores commodi omnis voluptatibus fugiat repellat nemo, maxime explicabo architecto nostrum officia, quisquam dignissimos deserunt perferendis soluta!</p>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script src="https://unpkg.com/boxicons@2.1.4/dist/boxicons.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Your question is not clear. Please edit your question to better describe what you expect to happen versus what is actually happening. You may need to add some screenshots or sketches.

Comment: Hey. Yes it is difficult to explain. I added a screenshot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I’d suggest fixed positioning for the two main panels, then a grid for managing the cards inside the `member-content` panel. I'm assuming that you’d want the content in the cards to scroll in case of overflow.

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Work+Sans:wght@500&display=swap');

body {
  font-family: Work Sans, sans-serif; 
}

.side-bar-left {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 250px;
  background-color: #2b479a;
  color: white;
  padding: 1em;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  overflow: auto;
}

.side-bar-left nav {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  gap: 1em;
}

.side-bar-left nav a {
  color: inherit;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.member-content {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 250px;
  right: 0;
  background-color: #f1f3f7;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 250px auto;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 2fr;
  gap: 1em;
  padding: 1em;
}

.member-content>* {
  padding: 1em;
  background-color: #fff;
  box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15) 2.4px 2.4px 3.2px;
  border-radius: 1em;
  overflow: auto;
}

.member-content>*>*:first-child {
  margin-top: 0;
}

.member-content>*>*:last-child {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.member-content .split-top {
  grid-column: 1 / span 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="side-bar-left">
  <nav>
    <a href="">Products</a>
    <a href="">Product Detail</a>
    <a href="">Orders</a>
    <a href="">See my portfolio</a>
  </nav>
</div>

<div class="member-content">

  <div class="split-top">
    <h2>This is the split-top</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Vel quibusdam quaerat suscipit consequuntur maiores commodi omnis voluptatibus fugiat repellat nemo, maxime explicabo architecto nostrum officia, quisquam dignissimos deserunt perferendis soluta!</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Vel quibusdam quaerat suscipit consequuntur maiores commodi omnis voluptatibus fugiat repellat nemo, maxime explicabo architecto nostrum officia, quisquam dignissimos deserunt perferendis soluta!</p>
  </div>

  <div class="split-bottom-left">
    <h2>This is the left split-bottom-left</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Vel quibusdam quaerat suscipit consequuntur maiores commodi omnis voluptatibus fugiat repellat nemo, maxime explicabo architecto nostrum officia, quisquam dignissimos deserunt perferendis soluta!</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Vel quibusdam quaerat suscipit consequuntur maiores commodi omnis voluptatibus fugiat repellat nemo, maxime explicabo architecto nostrum officia, quisquam dignissimos deserunt perferendis soluta!</p>
  </div>

  <div class="split-bottom-right">
    <h2>This is the right split-bottom-right</h2>
    <p>Some text here too.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Vel quibusdam quaerat suscipit consequuntur maiores commodi omnis voluptatibus fugiat repellat nemo, maxime explicabo architecto nostrum officia, quisquam dignissimos deserunt perferendis soluta!</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Vel quibusdam quaerat suscipit consequuntur maiores commodi omnis voluptatibus fugiat repellat nemo, maxime explicabo architecto nostrum officia, quisquam dignissimos deserunt perferendis soluta!</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Vel quibusdam quaerat suscipit consequuntur maiores commodi omnis voluptatibus fugiat repellat nemo, maxime explicabo architecto nostrum officia, quisquam dignissimos deserunt perferendis soluta!</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Vel quibusdam quaerat suscipit consequuntur maiores commodi omnis voluptatibus fugiat repellat nemo, maxime explicabo architecto nostrum officia, quisquam dignissimos deserunt perferendis soluta!</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Vel quibusdam quaerat suscipit consequuntur maiores commodi omnis voluptatibus fugiat repellat nemo, maxime explicabo architecto nostrum officia, quisquam dignissimos deserunt perferendis soluta!</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Vel quibusdam quaerat suscipit consequuntur maiores commodi omnis voluptatibus fugiat repellat nemo, maxime explicabo architecto nostrum officia, quisquam dignissimos deserunt perferendis soluta!</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Vel quibusdam quaerat suscipit consequuntur maiores commodi omnis voluptatibus fugiat repellat nemo, maxime explicabo architecto nostrum officia, quisquam dignissimos deserunt perferendis soluta!</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Vel quibusdam quaerat suscipit consequuntur maiores commodi omnis voluptatibus fugiat repellat nemo, maxime explicabo architecto nostrum officia, quisquam dignissimos deserunt perferendis soluta!</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Vel quibusdam quaerat suscipit consequuntur maiores commodi omnis voluptatibus fugiat repellat nemo, maxime explicabo architecto nostrum officia, quisquam dignissimos deserunt perferendis soluta!</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Vel quibusdam quaerat suscipit consequuntur maiores commodi omnis voluptatibus fugiat repellat nemo, maxime explicabo architecto nostrum officia, quisquam dignissimos deserunt perferendis soluta!</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Vel quibusdam quaerat suscipit consequuntur maiores commodi omnis voluptatibus fugiat repellat nemo, maxime explicabo architecto nostrum officia, quisquam dignissimos deserunt perferendis soluta!</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Vel quibusdam quaerat suscipit consequuntur maiores commodi omnis voluptatibus fugiat repellat nemo, maxime explicabo architecto nostrum officia, quisquam dignissimos deserunt perferendis soluta!</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Vel quibusdam quaerat suscipit consequuntur maiores commodi omnis voluptatibus fugiat repellat nemo, maxime explicabo architecto nostrum officia, quisquam dignissimos deserunt perferendis soluta!</p>
  </div>
</div>
```